# Android fragment with viewPager recreating

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Facing little trouble using fragments.
I have an activity with `NavigationDrawer`. When i click on `items` in `navigationMenu` `ItemFragment` is called. Inside the `ItemFragment` i have a `TabLayout` and `ViewPager` having two fragments.

```
1. GoodsFragment
2. ServiceFragment
```

The problem is the goods and service fragments are recreated inside the items fragment when ever i call itemfragment. i tried with savedInstanceState(true), (false) and also checking the rootview for null and many solutions but didn't help me out. Each time when fragment created there are two more extra fragments created. Beginner and tried many ways but helpless.
Here is my Code. and Thanks in advance.

**Item.java**

```
public class Items extends Fragment {

    @Nullable

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraglayout_items, container, false);
}
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);
}
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
    getActivity().setTitle("Items");
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Goods"));
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Services"));
    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);
    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PageAdapter adapter = new PageAdapter(getActivity().getFragmentManager(),tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
    tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Service_Fragment.java**

```
public class Service_fragment extends Fragment {
    public Service_fragment(){}
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fraglayout_service, container, false);
    }@Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        //you can set the title for your toolbar here for different fragments different titles
        ItemDatabaseHandler db=new ItemDatabaseHandler(view.getContext());
        ListView sList=(ListView)view.findViewById(R.id.service_list);
        List<ItemDataModel> items = db.getAllServices();
        ArrayList<Map<String, String>> data = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

        for (ItemDataModel item : items) {
            Map<String, String> datum = new HashMap<String, String>(2);
            datum.put("name", item.getName());
            datum.put("price", "\u20B9"+item.getPrice());
            datum.put("available", ""+item.getS_final());
            data.add(datum);
        }

        SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(view.getContext(), data, R.layout.item_row, new String[] {"name", "price","available"}, new int[] {R.id.item_name, R.id.item_price,R.id.item_available});
        sList.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

`Goods_fragment.java` is also save as service with class name changes. 
Also tried to destroy item fragment in `onDetach` but no luck.

**MainActivity.java**

package co.mastersindia.autotax;

```
import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.design.widget.NavigationView;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    public final static int REQUEST_CODE = 10101;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        displaySelectedScreen(R.id.nav_createinvoice);

    }
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
            drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        } else {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
    @Override
    public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
        displaySelectedScreen(item.getItemId());
        return true;
    }
    private void displaySelectedScreen(int itemId) {

        //creating fragment object
        Fragment fragment = null;

        //initializing the fragment object which is selected
        switch (itemId) {
            case R.id.nav_createinvoice:
                fragment = new CreateInvoice();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_viewinvoice:
                fragment = new ViewInvoice();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_tax:
                fragment = new Tax();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_items:
                fragment = new Items();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_busmgmt:
                fragment = new BusinessManagement();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_settings:
                Intent i=new Intent(MainActivity.this,SettingsActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);
                break;
            case R.id.nav_customers:
                fragment = new Customer();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_suppliers:
                fragment = new Suppliers();
                break;
            case R.id.nav_cat:
                fragment = new Categories();
                break;
        }

        //replacing the fragment
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
            transaction.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment);
            transaction.commit();
        }

        DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can u add your PageAdapter code?? How do you initialize and add these two fragments in item fragment?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Please find the edit for the code. @appLogic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who is facing this issue do this:
use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getSupportFragmentManager()`

```
ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter each time you move to a position it recreates the fragment. Check the above example code:

Initialise your view pager:

```
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewPager(viewPager);
```

In setupViewPager add an instance of your fragments:

```
    private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    ViewPagerAdapter adapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFrag(new OneFragment(), "ONE");
    adapter.addFrag(new TwoFragment(), "TWO");
    adapter.addFrag(new ThreeFragment(), "THREE");
    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

And then in your fragment when you move to that position just get the stored fragment from the array like the above example adapter.

```
    class ViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public ViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager manager) {
        super(manager);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }

    public void addFrag(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }
}
```

**Update**

When you create your each fragment you have to add a unique id to each one so as to be able to check if it already exists. Check the example below:

```
 FragmentManager fManager = getFragmentManager();
 FragmentTransaction fTransaction = fManager.beginTransaction();
 Fragment fragment = fManager.findFragmentByTag("uniqueTag");
 if (fragment == null) {
     fTransaction.add(R.id.fragment_list, new ListFrag(), "uniqueTag");
     else { // re-use the old fragment
     fTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_list, fragment, "uniqueTag");
```

Comment: please find the updated code. I have done the changes but the fragments are still being recreated.

Comment: If you recreate the itam fragment then the fragments will be recreated. When you click on your navigation drawer check if the item fragment is visible so just close your drawer

Comment: No. It is being recreated when i get back from another fragment. For example: when i first open the app and enter item_fragment there is no issue. Without closing the app and if i go to another fragment and come back to item_fragment it is being recreated but not when i call item_fragment from item_fragment. Sorry if i couldn't explain you clearly.

Comment: Can you add your code where you call your fragments from your drawer? How you get back to your item fragment that is already created. I think that you are recreating the item fragment so thats why the items inside it are being recreated again

Comment: under peer review. Can't chat as low reputation.

Comment: Just delete your page adapter code from the question end add the navigation drawer code for the fragment call. I am from my mobile so it would be easier for me to check it

Comment: Done. Removed and added MainActivity.java

Comment: When call displaySelectedScreen you actually recreate the whole fragment each time. You should check if each fragment is already created so just bring it infront. I will update my answer with code

Comment: Sorry. I added the code of yours in the seitch case by giving the unique id. But the result is only the first fragment is displayed the same for every other option.

Comment: Thats because u have to create a fragment varable for each one of your fragments

Comment: if(itemId==R.id.nav_items) {
                fM = getSupportFragmentManager();
                ftran = fM.beginTransaction();
                Fragment fragment = fM.findFragmentByTag("items");
                if (fragment == null) {
                    ftran.add(R.id.content_frame, new Items(), "items");
                    ftran.commit();
                } else {
                    ftran.replace(R.id.content_frame, fragment, "items");
                    ftran.commit();
                }
            }